# How to get a dynamic picklist in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Has someone an idea how to get dynamic picklist widgets in the object window! Eg. You choose a country in a picklist so the next picklist only shows cities in that country! I know that you could program your own widget but i can not find any example.
Maybe there is even a simpler solution or workaround! I would be happy for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The relatively new plugin "Form Value Relation" would appear to do what you are seeking

from the plugin description: "This widget can be used to implement drill-down forms, where the values available in one field depend on the values of other fields."